# nestjs+fastify stopped working after upgrade

Tags: node.js, nestjs, fastify, nestjs-fastify

What I did:
I upgrade nest js using `nest update -f -t latest`, the package version diffs are below.

before

```
"@nestjs/bull": "^0.1.1",
"@nestjs/common": "^7.0.7",
"@nestjs/core": "^7.0.7",
"@nestjs/graphql": "^7.3.7",
"@nestjs/platform-fastify": "^7.0.7",
"@nestjs/schedule": "^0.4.0",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.0.0",
```

after

```
"@nestjs/bull": "^0.3.0",
"@nestjs/common": "^7.5.4",
"@nestjs/core": "^7.5.4",
"@nestjs/graphql": "^7.8.2",
"@nestjs/platform-fastify": "^7.5.4",
"@nestjs/schedule": "^0.4.1",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.5",
```

(js versions: NodeJS 14.15.1 / TypeScript 4.0.5)

After the upgrade, when I start the nestjs server with nestjs v7.5.4 & fastify platform v7.5.4 I get

```
node_modules/@nestjs/platform-fastify/adapters/fastify-adapter.d.ts:21:315 - error TS2707: Generic type 'FastifyRequest<RouteGeneric, RawServer, RawRequest, HttpRequest, Query, Params, Headers, Body>' requires between 4 and 8 type arguments.
21 export declare class FastifyAdapter<TServer extends RawServerBase = RawServerDefault, TRawRequest extends RawRequestDefaultExpression<TServer> = RawRequestDefaultExpression<TServer>, TRawResponse extends RawReplyDefaultExpression<TServer> = RawReplyDefaultExpression<TServer>> extends AbstractHttpAdapter<TServer, FastifyRequest<RequestGenericInterface, TServer, TRawRequest>, FastifyReply<TServer, TRawRequest, TRawResponse>> {
```

but this error comes from node_modules@nestjs/platform-fastify so I cannot really touch the code...
Is there any way to avoid this error...?

Comment: I think you should downgrade `@nestjs/platform-fastify` because of [this issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5171)

Comment: thank you. when I use @nestjs/platform-fastify 7.2.0 (which uses fastify 2) it works fine. So I'll just use this version until the issue is resolved.